# java 8 stream for sorting a list of objects based on particular field

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, comparator

I have a scenario to sort the objects based on timestamp. The classes are as follows:

```
class Employee 
{
    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    //...
    //Getters and setters for all fields
}

public class Address
{
    private String city;
    private Timestamp startDate;
    private Timestamp endDate;
    private String typeOfResidence;

    //...
    //Getters and setters for all the fields
}
```

For an employee, there are 2 possibilities 
1. it will have a list of address.
2. the list of address can be null

The address class has a field `typeOfResidence` which can have values such as Residence, Office, ForeignHome.

Each `Employee` can have list of address, one address will be Residential, other Office and so on. There can be multiple Residential addresses but only one Office address.

I want to sort the list of employees based on startDate of Address whose typeOfResidence=Office.

I have written the following code:

```
private void sortEmployeeListBasedOnStartDate(List<Employee> employeeList)
{
    Comparator<Address> byTimeStamp = Comparator.comparing(
        Address::getStarteDate,
        (ts1, ts2) -> ts1.toGregorianCalendar().compareTo(ts2.toGregorianCalendar())
    );

    employeeList.stream()
        .map(x -> getLatestAddressByType(x, "Office"))
        .filter(y -> y!=null)
        .sorted(byTimeStamp.reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public Address getLatestAddressByType(Employee employee, String type)
{
    if(role != null && brokerageManagedProposalType != null)
    {
         return getUserAddress(employee).stream()
            .filter(address-> address.getTypeOfResidence().equals(type))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Address> getUserAddress(Employee employee)
{
    if (!NullChecker.isNull(employee) && !NullChecker.isNull(employee.getAddress()))
    {
        return employee.getAddress();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Somehow this does not seem to be working. The employees are not sorted. Please help me to make it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want in-place sorting, you can use `Collections.sort` instead of streams.

```
Collections.sort(employeeList, 
    (e1,e2) -> byTimeStamp.compare(
        getLatestAddressByType(e2, "Office"),
        getLatestAddressByType(e1, "Office") );
```

Similarly, the `null`-filtering issue can be solved in-place as follows:

```
employeeList.removeIf(e -> getLatestAddressByType(e, "Office") == null);
```

(btw, `getLatestAddressByType` should probably be an instance method of `Employee`)

Comment: Is there any way that null check and sorting can be combined in a single statement?

Comment: @azaveri7 Yes, you can plug the second statement as the first argument of "sort", but I would advise against it for readability.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco.

Answer (score 5):

Your `sortEmployeeListBasedOnStartDate` method doesn't mutate the input `List<Employee>`. It creates a new sorted `List<Address>`, which you do nothing with.

If you want a sorted `List<Employee>`, you shouldn't be mapping the `Employee`s to `Address`es. You should produce a sorted `List<Employee>` and return that `List`.

Something like this should do:

```
private List<Employee> sortEmployeeListBasedOnStartDate(List<Employee> employeeList)
{
    Comparator<Address> byTimeStamp = Comparator.comparing(
        Address::getStarteDate,
        (ts1, ts2) -> ts1.toGregorianCalendar().compareTo(ts2.toGregorianCalendar())
    );

    return employeeList
        .stream()
        .sorted((e1,e2)->byTimeStamp.compare(getLatestAddressByType(e2, "Office"),getLatestAddressByType(e1, "Office")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You might have to add some handling for the case where `getLatestAddressByType()` returns `null`:

```
    return employeeList
        .stream()
        .filter(e->getLatestAddressByType(e, "Office") != null)
        .sorted((e1,e2)->byTimeStamp.compare(getLatestAddressByType(e2, "Office"),getLatestAddressByType(e1, "Office")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
employeeList.stream()
    .map(x -> getLatestAddressByType(x, "Office"))
    .filter(y -> y!=null)
    .sorted(byTimeStamp.reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is not an in-place sort. The values in `employeeList` remain exactly the same. `collect` is creating a new `List` instance which is never assigned to a variable or returned - the instance is simply created and then immediately illegible for garbage collection.